# Unable to invoke 'hadoop jar' command for class, which contains Spring persistance unit

Tags: hadoop, spring-data

The problem is that, the jar file uses Spring ORM for loading the persistance configurations, and based on these configurations, files are moved to suitable folders in HDFS. Now If i use, 'java -cp' instead of 'hadoop jar', it fails to copy to HDFS, with FileSystem error.

While invoking the jar with hadoop jar command (having spring orm injected) the exception is as:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name

> 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0'
>   defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml
>
> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [applicationContext.xml]:  Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Conflicting persistence unit definitions for name 'Persistance':
>   file:/home/user/Desktop/ABC/apnJar.jar,
>   file:/tmp/hadoop-ABC/hadoop-unjar2841422106164401019/
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting persistence
>   unit definitions for name 'Persistance'

Seems like Hadoop is unpacking the jar file to some tmp folder, is this really required?
Can we skip this step by any configuration change?

Any thoughts on this are welcome.

Comment: Can you post your shell invocation line, as well as where in your job you're getting this error message (during job submission, at map/reduce task time?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use "hadoop jar", hadoop will run **org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar**. **RunJar** will unpackage your jar into a temp folder(In your case is /tmp/hadoop-ABC/hadoop-unjar2841422106164401019/) and load it in the current class loader. At last, it will invoke your main class to run your MapReduce application.

Did you add your jar in the CLASSPATH? If so, you will have your jar and the unpackaged folder in the class loader. I think that's why spring complains it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   The jar is available in the location, where I am executing the command. Is there any option, in command line, not to unpackage it ?

Comment: I can not find any option. You can view the codes of RunJar here: http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/util/RunJar.java#RunJar

Comment: You can try not to add your jar in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Yup..got the issue...the configuration files (persistence) are also available in the jar file, hence while unjar, it creates a copy of those too in tmp location, as a result, there are two persistence unit with the same name, and hence the conflict arises

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, I extracted the configuration xmls from the jar, and placed them in the working directory.

This worked, however looking for the proper solution.

Hence If you are facing the similar issue, remove all configuration xmls and place the jar with only the compiled class files.